# position inconsistency with carousel indicators

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using this code to create a basic carousel slider with 4 items.When I go to next slides it works well but when I navigate to first slide via carousel indicators, the carousel indicator's position becomes inconsistent.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div id="imageCarousel" class="carousel slide"  data-interval="2000">
                    <div class="carousel-indicators">
                        <ol>
                            <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active" ></li>
                            <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
                            <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
                            <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="3" ></li>

                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img src="Images/img1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Image 1</h3>
                                <p>This is the description for Image1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="Images/img2.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Image 2</h3>
                                <p>This is the description for Image2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="Images/img3.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Image 3</h3>
                                <p>This is the description for Image3</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="Images/img4.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Image 4</h3>
                                <p>This is the description for Image4</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(imageCarousel).carousel();
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the first slide when the page loads. It works well when I go to next slides.

[image]

But when I navigate to the first slide I face with some inconsistency with carousel position, here is the second snapshot.

[image]

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are initializing your carousel correctly?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#imageCarousel').carousel();
    });
```

I found the problem, your markup is wrong. `ol` must have `carousel-indicators` class but you wrap this to `div`. Correct markup is:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">

                            <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active" ></li>
                            <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
                            <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
                            <li data-target="#imageCarousel" data-slide-to="3" ></li>

                        </ol>
```

Look here for more details:
https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

And this is the working[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bpsbesr/)

Comment: Same problem again

Comment: Edited my answer. Your markup for `carousel-indicators` was wrong.